# Reading and Uploading files in java

Tags: java, csv, input

How do I iterate through a directory to read *.csv files and upload them in my system in Java?

Ignore the upload part of post.

Comment: well upload them in my system. I read each file and manipulate the data and upload that data in my system.

Comment: There's still ambiguity or misconception on the term "upload" you use there. You should clarify more.

Comment: I assume you mean "load" CSV files into a Java process.  "upload" generally means transmission to a separate server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this to locate all the files in your directory that have a `.csv` extension.

```
File[] files = new File(DIR_LOCATION).listFiles(new FileFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File file) {
        return file.getName().endsWith(".csv");
    }
});
```

Take a look at the [File I/O](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html) section of the java tutorial

Comment: you have a typo: `endsWith(".pdf")` instead of `endsWith(".csv")`.

Answer (score 1):

Give more specifics. Are you talking about a web application or a standalone application. Simple answer is if it is a web application you can't do that as you can upload only files using file control. If its a standalone app, you can read the dir using `list` method of file and check if the extension is csv and read it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`File#listFiles()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28java.io.FilenameFilter%29) in combination with [`FilenameFilter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FilenameFilter.html) to obtain CSV files of a given directory.

```
File directory = new File("/path/to/your/dir");
File[] csvFiles = directory.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
    @Override public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return name.endsWith(".csv");
    }
});
```

The remnant of the answer depends on how and where you'd like to upload it to. If it's a FTP service, then you'd like to use [Apache Commons Net](http://commons.apache.org/net) [FTPClient](http://commons.apache.org/net/api/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html). If it's a HTTP service, then you'd like to use [Apache HttpComponents Client](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client/index.html) [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html). If you edit your question to clarify the functional requirement, then I may update this answer to include more detail. You should however be aware that you need some sort of a server on the other side to be able to connect and send/upload the file to. E.g. a FTP or HTTP (web) server.

Answer (score 0):

Read Sun's tutorial on this:

http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/dirs.html

Answer (score 0):

File.list() will get you all the files in a given directory. File.list() returns it as an array of Strings; File.listFiles() returns it as an array of File objects.

You can then loop through the array and pick out all the ones that end in ".csv".

If you want to be a little more sophisticated, create a FilenameFilter that only passes csv files.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [File API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html).  Specifically, the File.list* methods; those will list the files in a directory.